# iframe removing CSS after updating via srcdoc - How to make added CSS persist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to implement a "Light/Dark Mode" feature to a real time text editor, however due to the use of srcdoc the iframe refreshes and removes any CSS applied to it via JQuery. I would like to be able to keep the CSS within the iframe's contents.

I've attempted to make use of .css() to the contents of my frame, which works, but since I'm refreshing the frame on each keyUp event, the CSS is refreshed and no longer applied.

Appending the stylesheet also seems to result in it being "cleared" when refreshing.

How can I get the CSS to stay applied to the frame?

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <textarea id="text-input" onkeyup="refresh()" placeholder="Enter your code here.."></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <iframe id="output-display"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function refresh(){
 var input = document.getElementById('text-input').value;
 document.getElementById('output-display').srcdoc = input;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#output-display').contents().find('body').css('color', 'white');
});
```

**EDIT:**

The aim of this is to be a Real Time Editor, allowing a user to enter some code on the left (text area) and the result to be displayed on the right (iframe)

Comment: Why use an iframe at all though, looks like you just want a text input which is shown somewhere else as it is being typed? Or is your actual usecase different?

Comment: I should've clarified that better, the aim is to be able to run code through this editor, hence the use of the iframe. - Added edit to main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think you don't actually have to use an `iframe` to accomplish what you are going for here. You could just use a regular html element and set the content at every keypress. Please see the code snippet below for reference:

```js
var isDark = false;
function toggleTheme() {
  if(isDark) {
    $('#output-display').css({'background-color': 'black', 'color': 'white'});
    isDark = false;
  } else {
    $('#output-display').css({'background-color': 'white', 'color': 'black'});
    isDark = true;
  }
}

function refresh() {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('text-input').value;
  var parsedHtml = $.parseHTML(inputValue, document, true);
  $('#output-display').html($(parsedHtml));
}
toggleTheme();
refresh();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="button" onclick="toggleTheme()" value="Toggle Theme" />
<br>
  <textarea id="text-input" onkeyup="refresh()" placeholder="Enter your code here.."></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height: 300px" id="output-display" disabled></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** added a theme toggle to illustrate further how you could use this.

**EDIT2:** added `.parseHTML` so you can add html to the input and render it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using iframe as I want any code typed into the textarea to be displayed as it would in a standard DOM. I.e <b></b> makes text bold, adding <style> effects the elements etc etc

Comment: Glad I could help!